# Regex - match only when word doesnt have any other chars behind

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match a word with regex which doesnt have any follows?

for example:

```
TEST --> match
TEST() --> doenst match
(TEST) --> match
(TEST --> match
TEST) --> match
TEST+ --> doesnt match
TEST/ --> doesnt match
```

Comment: `\(?TEST\)?`, use anchors to complete match

Comment: mentioning/adding the language in Tags, helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to fail the match if certain chars are found ahead of your match.

```
/\b\w+\b(?![\/+(])/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB1aI1/2)

Comment: ok see updated answer. Better you clarify this in your question.